# Margin only between two buttons in responsive grid (jquery mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, grid

I just want to have a space between two buttons using a responsive grid in jquery mobile, and I dont want margin in the left and right side of the buttons . And I cant figure how.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/getuliodtj/yu4pem1g/2/) is showing what I want: when there´s horizontal space, there´s one button in the left side, other button on the right side and a space in the middle. And there´s no margin in the left side of the left button, and no margin in the right side of right button: perfect! Exactly what I want.

[image]

This is how I achieve this result:

```
.ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-a]>.ui-btn { margin:0 10px 0 0; }
.ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-b]>.ui-btn { margin:0 0 0 10px; }
```

But... when we squeeze the horizontal space to turn it responsive, I will have a space in the right size of the first button, and a space in the left side of the second button (the left and right margin of css, of course):

[image]

The question is: how to have the space between the buttons (like the first image) and not have this spaces when responsive (problem in the second image)? using some kind of 'spacer' between the two buttons? another div? I really tried many things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
@media (max-width:800px) {
  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-btn {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yu4pem1g/3/**

Comment: Interesting @praveen-kumar but this way I only see the space between the two buttons if the horizontal space is >= 800px, right? And I want to see the space between the buttons always (like my jsfiddle shows)...

Comment: Yes, you need to change the `max-width` as per your requirement.

Comment: @pierre, jQM's default breakpoint is 35em: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yu4pem1g/4/

Comment: Now I understood the concept. Thanks @praveen-kumar and thanks @ezanker! Now it´s working perfectly, and I learned a lot with this! Thanks.